# React - Communicate between Material UI Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI's nested/select ItemList component to dynamically generates any number of dropdown menu items based on how many items belong in this header as you can maybe tell from the mapping function. On another file 1 layer above this one, I am again mapping and generating multiple of these DropDownMenus, is it possible for these components to communicate to each other?

This is the file in question

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 330,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
  }
}));

export default function DropDownMenu(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  
  let unitName = props.unit[0];
  let chapterList = props.unit.slice(1);

  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (index) => {
    console.log("ItemClicked");
    console.log(index);
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const selectMenuItem = (chapter, index) => {
    props.chooseChapter(chapter)
    handleListItemClick(index)
  }


  let dropDownUnit = chapterList.map((chapter, index) => {
    return (
        <ListItem button 
        className={classes.selected}
        selected={selectedIndex === index}
        onClick={() => selectMenuItem(chapter, index)}
        key={index}>
          <ListItemText primary={chapter} />
        </ListItem>
    )
  })

  return (
    <List
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
        </ListSubheader>
      }
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemText primary={unitName} />
        {!open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={!open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding className={classes.selected}>
          {dropDownUnit}
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
        
  );
}
```

Psudo Style - What I'm trying to accomplish

```
<DropDownMenu>
   <MenuItem>  // Suppose this is selected
   <MenuItem>
<DropDownMenu>
   <MenuItem>  // onClick --> Select this and deselect all other selected buttons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a parent of these components such that the parent will keep the state of who is active. That way you can pass that state & the state setter as props so that everyone will know who is active

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState();

  return (
    <>
      <DropDownMenu
        selectedItem={selectedItem} // pass down as props
        setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} // pass down as props
        unit={...}
        chooseChapter={function () {}}
      />
      ...
```

On the children, simply refactor the Call To Action (in this case `onClick`) to set the state using the passed down props. Pay attention to the `selected` prop of `ListItem`, we now use the state we have passed down from the parent

```
let dropDownUnit = chapterList.map((chapter, index) => {
  return (
    <ListItem
      button
      className={classes.selected}
      selected={props.selectedItem === chapter}
      onClick={() => props.setSelectedItem(chapter)}
      key={index}
    >
      <ListItemText primary={chapter} />
    </ListItem>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit snowy-violet-e8d82]

Comment: Yes, although I have to tweak the code a bit to fit my specifics, this helped me understand what I needed to do to get it to work. Thanks!